# Android ToggleButton Combination

Tags: android, listview, if-statement, togglebutton

I'm using 3 ToggleButtons (A,B,C) to filter the content of my array (with an AND condition) and show the result in a listview.

For example
if A is true and B,C false... the listview will only show me the items in my array that only contains A. if A,B is true and C is false. The listview will show the items in my array with A AND B.

I'm doing this with onCheckedChangeListener something like:

```
 @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        List<BrandPlanners> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (isChecked){
            if (buttonView == A) {
                if (B.isChecked()){
                    if (C.isChecked()){
                        //show listview with A,B and C elements
                    } else {
                        // show listview with A AND B elements
                    }
                } else {
                    if (C.isChecked()){
                        // Show listview with A and C elements
                    } else {
                        // Show listview with A elements
                    }
                }
            }
            if (buttonView == B) {
                if (A.isChecked()){
                    if (C.isChecked()){
                        // show listview with 3 elements
                    } else {
                        // show listview whth A and B elements
                    }
                } else {
                    if (C.isChecked()){
                        // show listview with C and B elements                    
                    } else {
                        // show listview with B elements
                    }
                }
            }
            if (buttonView == C) {
                if (A.isChecked()){
                    if (B.isChecked()){
                        // show 3 elements
                    } else {
                        // show C and A elements
                    }
                } else {
                    if (B.isChecked()){
                        // show C and B elements
                    } else {
                        // show C elements
                    }
                }
            }
        } else { //if isChecked() is false
            //create all the if conditions again
        }
    }
```

I think this is not a good practice, the question is: How can i do this in a better way? this is actually working but i am not happy with the code.

Comment: Can you give the code of show X elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your adapter implement `Filterable`. Check the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html).

About the code, add a method for each row that returns a bitmap (a single `char` would work) and with the information about having A, B or C associated to a single bit.

For example: bit 0 for A, bit 1 for B and bit 2 for C

So `0x01` would mean that that row has A but not B nor C

The whole code you wrote would be as simple as

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    char filter = 0x00;
    filter += A.isChecked() ? 1 : 0;
    filter += B.isChecked() ? 2 : 0;
    filter += C.isChecked() ? 4 : 0;

    for each element (
        if (element.getObjectsAsBits() == filter)
            show(element);
    )
}
```

P.D. I know that code won't work. It's just pseudocode so you get an idea

Comment: with this pseudo it means that:
0x01 = A
0x02 = B
0x03 = A AND B
0x04 = C
0x05 = A AND C
0x06 = B AND C
0x07 = A AND B AND C

right?

Answer (score 0):

```
aCondition = ((buttonView == A && isChecked) || A.isChecked());
bCondition = ((buttonView == B && isChecked) || B.isChecked());
cCondition = ((buttonView == C && isChecked) || C.isChecked());

A.setVisibility(aCondition ? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);
B.setVisibility(bCondition ? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);
C.setVisibility(cCondition ? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);
```

It can be also shorter, like this:

```
public void checkButton(Button buttonView, Button button){
    button.setVisibility((buttonView == button && isChecked) || button.isChecked() ? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);
}

checkButton(buttonView, A); 
checkButton(buttonView, B);
checkButton(buttonView, C);
```

Btw, I suggest you not to use variables with the first letter in uppercase (like A, B or C) since usually they are or constants or class names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm just filtering the data through buttons... i'm not changing the view of the elements, and btw, my variables aren't A,B and C... is just an example.

Comment: then it's the same thing I suppose. Like instead of:

A.setVisibility(etc.)

just do

aCondition? //listView enable A element : //listView disable A element